# Mount an ext3 partition with a 16k blocksize?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, ext3, gentoo

We are attempting to recover data from a drive which was formated by Netgear ReadyNas Duo.  We have dropped it in a linux box and discovered that it is formated as ext3 with a 16k block size. Mounting it on a linux box returns the following error.

```
EXT3-fs: bad blocksize 16384.
```

We have been looking for a Linux live cd which supports the 16k block size by default and have been unsuccessful. Is there an easier way to do this other than compiling this feature in the kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block sizes >4KiB are only available on architectures which support larger virtual memory pages (e.g. Alpha, Itanium).

Comment: and SPARC (which is what the ReadyNas has)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use fuseext2 to mount the drive. I recently did this and while it worked, it was very unstable. Not sure if it was the drive, SATA controller or the fuse module. The mount would disappear randomly. I ended up having to watch an rsync job for 2 weeks, if it crashed, I would have to recreate the mount and start the job up again.

The basic mount command is:

fuseext2 -o sync_read,allow_other,ro /dev/c/c /mnt/readynas

More details are available at this page:

http://home.bott.ca/webserver/?p=306